# Extract text between symbols with bash

Tags: awk, sed

First off, I am relatively new at this, so please bear with me.

I have an annotated transcriptome .fasta file, which contains ~60,000 records of genes like these two:

```
>comp35897_c0_seq11 len=1039 path=[11:0-12;24:13-1038] Match_Acc=E5SX33 Gene=Putative_CAP-Gly_domain_protein 
TTTTAAATTGATTACTTTGCTATTTTTGGCAATGTTGGACTGAGTTGTCGTATTTTTTCG
>comp32620_c0_seq3 len=1874 path=[1:0-195;197:196-220;222:221-354;356:355-481;4197:482-487;489:488-579;581:580-1159;1161:1160-1712;1714:1713-1729;1731:1730-1794;5873:1795-1873] Match_Acc=K1PQJ1 Gene=HAUS_augmin-like_complex_subunit_3 GO=GO:0051225,GO:0070652 
CAGACTTTTGGATTTAGTACATGTATGTATGAATATGTGTTTCAATGTACAACTCAGGAT
```

I am trying to create a two-column, space-delimited .tab with component number in the first column and gene name in the second column. I have looked at many similar posts using `grep`, `sed`, or `awk`, but none of the suggested code has worked for me.

Specifically, what I need to pull from the .fasta is the comp number between the `>` and the next `space` for the first column, and gene name between `Gene=`and the next `space`. For the two genes above, that should give me:

```
comp35897_c0_seq11 Putative_CAP-Gly_domain_protein
comp32620_c0_seq3 HAUS_augmin-like_complex_subunit_3
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: In the future, please realize that a 30 char set of data can equally represent your 300 char data set, thus making it easier to see where the active vs unneeded data is. Please compose your Qs with non genomic readers in mind (if you want them to help ;-) ). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with awk:

**Skip's gene name if 'gene' is absent**

```
   awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"} NF>1{if($5 ~ /Gene=/){gsub("Gene=","",$5); print $1,$5} else {print $1}}' < transcriptome.fasta > space-delimited.tab
```

*Output*:

```
comp35897_c0_seq11 Putative_CAP-Gly_domain_protein
comp32620_c0_seq3
```

**Skip's the record if 'gene' is absent**

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"} NF>1{if($5 ~ /Gene=/){gsub("Gene=","",$5); print $1,$5}}' < transcriptome.fasta > space-delimited.tab
```

*Output*:

```
comp35897_c0_seq11 Putative_CAP-Gly_domain_protein
```

Comment: This worked, except for genes that do not have a known gene name. For those genes , where `gene=` doesn't exist, the code is pulling some part of the sequence (ATCG). Is there a way to filter out components that do not have a gene name and not include them in the resulting table? `comp36636_c0_seq12 ATGATTTGGCCTGTTATTTGCCCTTCCCTGTAACTCCCATGGGGACTCATTTGTCCAGTG
comp35897_c0_seq11 Putative_CAP-Gly_domain_protein`

Comment: This worked! I'm using the second version that removes the whole row including component number if gene name is not present, but I may have to revisit this if I end up needing all the components regardless of whether they've been identified or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything yet?

with sed you could do:

```
sed 's/>\(comp[^ ]\+\) \+.*Gene=\([^ ]\+\) .*$/\1 \2/'
```

which looks complex but is relatively easy to understand if you take it slowly and break it down into it's component parts.

### edit

ok, so to ensure sed only outputs what you want, you need to switch on the 'no output by default' mode `-n` and explicitly print each line you are interested in `p`

I'll try to break it down, so that it is understandable.

```
comp[^ ]\+ #is a regex that says: 
           #text that starts with the string 'comp' 
           #and is followed by at least one character
           #that is anything that isn't a space (the [^ ]) 
\(comp[^ ]\+\) #is the sed construct that remembers what 
               #that regex matches.
.* #is the regex for zero or more of any chars.
'Gene=\([^ ]\+\) ' #look for the string 'Gene' followed by an
                   #equals sign, followed by at least one char
                   #that isn't a space, followed by a space
                   #oh, and remember the bit after = and before the space
```

so, along with the -n and the p switches for sed you could use:

```
sed -n 's/>\(comp[^ ]\+\) \+.*Gene=\([^ ]\+\) .*$/\1 \2/p'
```

Comment: I've tried a handful of sed and awk commands, but I guess I don't understand enough about the arguments to know what to change for my purposes. I did run your code however, and it worked to an extent. The output for the same two genes as above removed all the unnecessary information between the component number and gene name, but still included the whole sequence (ATCGs), shortened example below: `comp35897_c0_seq11 Putative_CAP-Gly_domain_protein
TTTTAAATTGATT...`
`comp32620_c0_seq3 HAUS_augmin-like_complex_subunit_3
CAGACTTTTGGA...`

Comment: It is printing the sequences because `sed` is only modifying (replacing) lines that match the search regular expression (between the first two `/`), leaving (and printing) the other lines unmodified.

Comment: i've edited my answer to (hopefully) assist your understanding